# Fetching an image from another server

Tags: php, html, image, curl

Say, for this example, this is an image: http://www.basitansari.com/wp-content/uploads/logoaba.png which is hosted on website A.

I am calling this image into website B with an `<img>` tag. If the owner of site A removes this image then how can I know that the image has been removed using PHP? If the owner of site A removes the image then I want to show a `notfound.jpg` image. Should I use cURL for this purpose, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the image server-side is definitely possible, but it may not be the best solution. Doing so means that all valid images will be loaded twice (once server-side and again by the client). A better method may be to use JavaScript to handle broken images. The following code will only take action if an error occurs while loading the image, replacing it with the image you specify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function brokenImage( obj ) {
    obj.onerror = '';
    obj.src = 'path/to/notfound.jpg';
    return true;
}
</script>
<img onerror="brokenImage(this);" src="broken.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$fp = fopen('http://www.basitansari.com/wp-content/uploads/logoaba.png', 'r')) {
  // The image cannot be retrieved, handle it here.
} else {
  fclose($fp);
}
```

This is the quickest way as it just checks that the image can be successfully retrieved, it doesn't download the whole file.

Comment: What if the image is 100s of megs? Why would he transfer it just to know if it is there? There are better ways to do it. See my answer

Comment: @Zepplock This does not transfer the whole image. Try it out. It only sends the request, reads the head and gets the socket ready to receive the data - the `fopen()` call returns as soon as it confirms whether the file is accessible or not. Granted this is what the `HEAD` method is supposed to do, but doing so requires (slightly) more code and requires that the server handle `HEAD` correctly, which there is always a chance it may not. This just initialises a `GET`, confirms whether or not it will work, and returns.

Comment: i just want to know that does this method slow down the page loading speed or not?

Comment: @DaveRandom: When server sees a GET it'll start sending the file. You are describing the HEAD functionality but claiming HEAD is not used. I don't have PHP here so I can't verify. I think it worked for `mindblaster` since the image is small and he didn't see a delay.

Comment: If the image successfully loads, it shouldn't add more than 100ms to the load time. If it does not load, it's anybody's guess - it depends *why* it is not loading. If the image has been removed and returns a 404, it should be about the same as a successful load. If the server is down, it will probably add [`default_socket_timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) seconds to the load time.

Comment: @Zepplock I have used this approach for a set of files that I have to retrieve once a month or so that are ~70MB and I can tell you that it works. What is happening underneath is that the socket is created, the request is made, and the response headers are parsed. `fopen()` then returns control to the script, while (if successful) in the background it continues to buffer a little data, then when it has a decent buffer it will stop sending `ACK`s to halt the stream. Check out [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yMkcpw) - takes under a second to get a whole 18MB file? I doubt it...

Answer (score 0):

You should call that URL with HEAD method and check if status code 404 (Not found) or 200 (OK)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i am trying this method now.

Answer (score 0):

You can call directly: Check if image source exists using fopen and if not show notfound.jpg. @ is used to supress warning

```
<img src="<?php if (@fopen("http://www.basitansari.com/wp-content/uploads/logoaba.png", "r")) {echo 'http://www.basitansari.com/wp-content/uploads/logoaba.png';} else{echo 'notfound.jpg';}?>" />
```